# Does emrfs support custom query parameters in s3 url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Is it possible to add customer query parameters in s3 url?

We would like to add some custom meta data to S3 objects, but would like it to be transparent to EMRFS

Something like:

s3://bucket-name/object-name?x-amz-meta-tag=magic-tag

Then in our PySpark or hadoop job, we would like to write:

data.write.csv('s3://bucket-name/object-name?x-amz-meta-tag=magic-tag')

Trying this on the emrfs shows that it treats "object-name?x-amz-meta-tag=magic-tag" as the entire object name instead of ignoring the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the closed source EMRFS, but for the ASF s3 connectors, the answer is "no". Interesting proposal though; maybe you should think about contributing it to the ASF. Of course, that adds a new problem: what if existing users are creating files with ? in their names —how to retain compatibility.